# Laravel worker failure because of Dead lock at JOBS table causing SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, laravel, innodb, supervisord

**Issue -**

I have failing workers because of Deadlock caused at JOBS table, while deleting entries of jobs.

This behaviour is frequent in occurrence, even over slight increase in traffic.

*Need suggestions to avoid this Deadlock ?*

**Configuration -**

- Using Laravel queues with QUEUE_DRIVER=database
- Supervisor as queue manger
- DB is MySQL

**Logs -**

```
{"message":"SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; 
try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 215520)","context":{"exception":{"class":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[40001]: 
Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction 
(SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 
215520)","code":40001,"file":"/home/aditya/Desktop/code/Chqbook-
api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664","previous":
{"class":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found 
when trying to get lock; try restarting 
transaction","code":40001,"file":"/home/aditya/Desktop/code/Chqbook-
api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:483"}}},"level":400,"level_n
ame":"ERROR","channel":"local","datetime":{"date":"2020-09-17 
07:22:56.546154","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia/Kolkata"},"extra":[]}

{"message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`,
```

Answer (score 3):

Deadlock and lock-wait-timeout are related problems.

You have 2 (or more) connections that are doing something with the same (or adjacent) row(s) of the same table(s).

MySQL has two actions it might take:

- Stall one connection until the other one releases the rows.  If the releasing takes "too" long, the waiting connection gives up with "wait lock timeout".  Moral of the story:  Don't write transactions that take more than a few seconds to complete:
- If each is waiting for the other, you have a "deadlock".  One connection's transaction is aborted.  Making the queries faster may decrease the frequency of deadlocking.  Being ready to re-execute a transaction is the ultimate way to deal with deadlocks.

Using MySQL as a queue manager tempts you to

1. grab an item from the queue
2. process it
3. remove the item from the query

It is logical to do all 3 of those steps in a transaction.  But, if step 2 takes "a long time", you are begging for one of the problems listed above.

A better approach is:

```
BEGIN  
1. Grab an item from the queue
2. Mark it as taken
COMMIT  

3. Process it at your leisure

BEGIN
4. Remove the item from the queue
COMMIT
```

Comment: Queues functionality is framework driven. I have NO control over it !

Comment: Perhaps there is a competing product?  Or do the job directly in MySQL.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We have the same problem here and we CANNOT use redis no more

Comment: @realtebo - Your situation might be subtly different.  Consider starting a separate Question and provide more details.  Please include timings and SQL, where practical.

Answer (score 2):

Taylor Otwell admited that mysql was never intended to be used for queues : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15192#issuecomment-252663714. There are many possible reasons why you are facing this issue.

Maybe you should consider using Redis instead of mysql for your queues (and why not with Horizon which is amazing)

Comment: I am trying to find source for ```Taylor Otwell admited that mysql was never intended to be used for queues.```

Unable. Kindly provide the same in comments . Thanks !

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15192#issuecomment-252663714

Comment: Horizon is for monitoring of queues and getting dashboards. How would that help in this issue?

Comment: It doesn't but if you decide to go with Redis, it's interesting to have this dashboard to monitor all your jobs

Comment: We cannot. REDIS keep all in RAM but our amount of jobs is exceding available RAM.